# Line break in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

Is it possible to have mutliple lines in command line (CMD)?
Something like

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a 
aaa.txt.hpp, 
bbb.txt, 
ccc.txt
```

instead of

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a aaa.txt.hpp, bbb.txt, ccc.txt
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a *"heave"*. It looks like a line *break* to me.

Comment: @CodyGray: I assume "heave" is a typo for "have". Edited.

Answer (score 30):

#### Is it possible to have multiple lines in command line?

Yes, you can do this by escaping the EOL character, like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a ^
aaa.txt.hpp, ^
bbb.txt, ^
ccc.txt
```

where `^` is the escape character.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: But how to type EOL from keyboard?

Comment: @vico Use the Enter key ... which inserts the appropriate EOL character(s)

Comment: @vico EOL means "End Of Line". There's more than one way shells do this, but your kernel manages it via your Enter key, so you never see exactly what's happening. It's usually not a problem unless you try to take text files formatted for one shell over to another.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't paste multiline commands into a command prompt... it treats each line as a separate command